# Why my changes won't show up in the zip/img file created by running 'm component'?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I build my aosp project by running:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch x86_64-userdebug
m component
```

I got the zip file created which inside there are different img files and others.
Then I modified some code in the aosp/vendor/myproduct/run.sh,
rerun:

```
m component
```

when I start the emulator with the new created zip file (unzip to ~/Android/system-images/ folder), I don't have my changes in the run.sh.
Thanks for sharing any idea.